# Kafka Getting error No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap servers

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm pretty sure the bootstrap.servers is correct. Is there anything confliction in Maven or what wrong with Kafka??

Before that It was working successfully. I added some Maven or Spark then something went wrong..

Can anyone knows how to resolve it?

Here is kafka code in java

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "x.xx.xxx.xxx:9092");
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "x.xx.xxx.xxx:9091, x.xx.xxx.xxx:9092, x.xx.xxx.xxx:9093");

        props.put("producer.type", "async");
        props.put("batch.size", "500");
        props.put("compression.codec", "1");
        props.put("compression.topic", topicName);
        props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

            org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(
                    props);
```

Getting error No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap servers,

```
[err]   at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:335)
    [err]   at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:188)
    [err]   at com.wra.controller.ParserController.GetResumeUpload(ParserController.java:98)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    [err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
    [err] Caused by: 
    [err] org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
    [err]   at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:59)
    [err]   at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:275)
    [err]   ... 51 more
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the IP instead of the server name? Maybe it is a name resolution issue

Comment: @Vimal Dhaduk, Did you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"metadata.broker.list" is deprecated and "bootstrap.servers" is used instead. Removing "metadata.broker.list" configuration from your code should resolve the problem. Please find more details at [difference between bootstrap.servers and metadata.broker.list](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/43258/difference-between-bootstrapservers-and-metadatabr.html)

Answer (score 6):

In my case,the bootstrap.servers were not in the host:port format

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thanks for help, i also configured bootstrap.servers as 127.0.0.1 instead of 127.0.0.1:9092. I added port and now it works.

Answer (score 6):

in my case simply company vpn was down and couldn't access servers

Answer (score 3):

For anyone encountering this issue with MapR client libraries, you will get this if you forget the / on the front of the stream name.

Answer (score 2):

This error can indicate a network connectivity issue. For example, it is triggered if the server host is unknown (no IP associated).

Answer (score 0):

I ran kafka broker and myapp with kafka client in different containers and in my case i did not added param `network`  when ran container with my app.

```
    docker run -it --rm --network example_network my_repo/my_image:my_tag
```

The `network (example_network)` has to be specified in the broker container.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in the the application.properties there was a property 'spring.profiles.active' set as 'stage' by default, changing that to 'local' resolved the error for me

```
spring.profiles.active = stage -> local
```